# Closing/Clearing Jni connections

Tags: java, java-native-interface, new-operator, reset

Anyone knows if there's a way to stop/reset the connection between a Java application and it's Jni linked C++ source... ?

I tried resetting the object by calling its constructor, but it doesn't work ...

> MyJniJavaClass jni = new MyJniJavaClass();
>
> ---- MY ACTIONS ----
>
> jni = new MyJniJavaClass();
>
> ---- OTHER ACTIONS ----

In fact, my problem is that I try to access my C++ DLL two times. It works well the first time and then crashes the second one...
I tried accessing the C++ DLL using two different object's instances but it still crashes ...

So I suppose that the problem is due to the fact that the C++ DLL stays open in my application memory and that it doesn't like me to access it twice ("at the same time")...

Here is the C++ code :

```
////////////////// ADDED
#include "stdafx.h" 

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <XtremeAPI.h> 
////////////////// ADDED

#include "MainFrame_Jni_Functions.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// parameters table columns and row number
vector<char*>   paramName;
vector<char*>   paramType;
jdouble*        paramValue;
jdouble*        paramMin;
jdouble*        paramMax;
jdouble*        paramRef;
jint            paramNbRows;

// responses table columns and row number
vector<char*>   respName;
jint            respNbRows;

// objectives table columns and row number
vector<char*>   objName;
vector<char*>   objType;
jint            objNbRows;

// constraints table columns and row number
vector<char*>   conName;
vector<char*>   conType;
jdouble*        conLimit;
jdouble*        conExponent;
jdouble*        conRefVal;
jdouble*        conWeight;
jint            conNbRows;

// interval constraints table columns and row number
vector<char*>   intConName;
vector<char*>   intConType;
jdouble*        intConLowLimit;
jdouble*        intConUpLimit;
jdouble*        intConExponent;
jdouble*        intConWeight;
jint            intConNbRows;

// Xtreme data's
//static XtremeDataGA       xtremeDataGA;
/*XtremeDataFastGA  xtremeDataFastGA;
XtremeDataMGA       xtremeDataMGa;
XtremeDataFastGA    xtremeDataFastGA;
XtremeDataFastMGA   xtremeDataFastMGA;*/


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MainFrame_Jni_Functions_sendParamToNative
(   JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj, jobjectArray jparamName, jdoubleArray jparamValue, 
jdoubleArray jparamMin, jdoubleArray jparamMax, jdoubleArray jparamRef, jobjectArray jparamType){

    paramNbRows = env->GetArrayLength( jparamName );

    paramValue  = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(jparamValue, 0);
    paramMin    = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(jparamMin, 0);
    paramMax    = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(jparamMax, 0);
    paramRef    = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(jparamRef, 0);
    
    paramName   = vector<char*>(paramNbRows);
    for(int i=0; i<paramNbRows; i++){ 
        paramName.at(i) =  (char*)env->GetStringUTFChars(
            (jstring)env->GetObjectArrayElement( jparamName, i), 0 );
    }

    paramType   = vector<char*>(paramNbRows);
    for(int i=0; i<paramNbRows; i++){ 
        paramType.at(i) =  (char*)env->GetStringUTFChars(
            (jstring)env->GetObjectArrayElement( jparamType, i), 0 );
    }

    env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(jparamValue,paramValue, 0);
    env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(jparamMin,  paramMin,   0);
    env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(jparamMax,  paramMax,   0);
    env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(jparamRef,  paramRef,   0);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MainFrame_Jni_Functions_sendRespToNative    (JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj, jobjectArray jRespName){        

respNbRows  = env->GetArrayLength( jRespName );

respName    = vector<char*>(respNbRows);
for(int i=0; i<respNbRows; i++){ 
    respName.at(i) =  (char*)env->GetStringUTFChars(
        (jstring)env->GetObjectArrayElement( jRespName, i), 0 );
}
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MainFrame_Jni_Functions_sendObjToNative  
(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj, jobjectArray jObjName, jobjectArray jObjType){
            
objNbRows   = env->GetArrayLength( jObjName );

objName     = vector<char*>(objNbRows);
for(int i=0; i<objNbRows; i++){ 
    objName.at(i) =  (char*)env->GetStringUTFChars(
        (jstring)env->GetObjectArrayElement( jObjName, i), 0 );
}

objType     = vector<char*>(objNbRows);
for(int i=0; i<objNbRows; i++){ 
    objType.at(i) =  (char*)env->GetStringUTFChars(
        (jstring)env->GetObjectArrayElement( jObjType, i), 0 );
}
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MainFrame_Jni_Functions_sendConToNative
(   JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj, jobjectArray jConName, jobjectArray jConType, 
    jdoubleArray jConLimit, jdoubleArray jConExpo, jdoubleArray jConRefVal, jdoubleArray jConWeight){

        conNbRows       = env->GetArrayLength( jConName );

        conLimit        = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(jConLimit, 0);
        conExponent     = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(jConExpo, 0);
        conRefVal       = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(jConRefVal, 0);
        conWeight       = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(jConWeight, 0);

        conName         = vector<char*>(conNbRows);
        for(int i=0; i<conNbRows; i++){ 
            conName.at(i) =  (char*)env->GetStringUTFChars(
                (jstring)env->GetObjectArrayElement( jConName, i), 0 );
        }

        conType         = vector<char*>(conNbRows);
        for(int i=0; i<conNbRows; i++){ 
            conType.at(i) =  (char*)env->GetStringUTFChars(
                (jstring)env->GetObjectArrayElement( jConType, i), 0 );
        }

        env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(jConLimit,  conLimit,   0);
        env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(jConExpo,   conExponent,0);
        env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(jConRefVal, conRefVal,  0);
        env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(jConWeight, conWeight,  0);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MainFrame_Jni_Functions_sendIntConToNative
(   JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj, jobjectArray jIntConName, jobjectArray jIntConType, 
    jdoubleArray jIntConLowLimit, jdoubleArray jIntConUpLimit, jdoubleArray jIntConExp, jdoubleArray jIntConWeight){

        intConNbRows = env->GetArrayLength( jIntConName );

        intConLowLimit  = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(jIntConLowLimit, 0);
        intConUpLimit   = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(jIntConUpLimit, 0);
        intConExponent  = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(jIntConExp, 0);
        intConWeight    = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(jIntConWeight, 0);

        intConName = vector<char*>(intConNbRows);
        for(int i=0; i<intConNbRows; i++){ 
            intConName.at(i) =  (char*)env->GetStringUTFChars(
                (jstring)env->GetObjectArrayElement( jIntConName, i), 0 );
        }

        intConType = vector<char*>(intConNbRows);
        for(int i=0; i<intConNbRows; i++){ 
            intConType.at(i) =  (char*)env->GetStringUTFChars(
                (jstring)env->GetObjectArrayElement( jIntConType, i), 0 );
        }

        env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(jIntConLowLimit,intConLowLimit, 0);
        env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(jIntConUpLimit, intConUpLimit,  0);
        env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(jIntConExp,     intConExponent, 0);
        env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(jIntConWeight,  intConWeight,   0);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MainFrame_Jni_Functions_printTables  (JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj){

cout    << endl << "Printing from XtremeAPIProject" << endl;

cout    << endl << "paramTable" << endl;
for(int i=0; i<paramNbRows; i++)
    cout    << "line " << i << " : "    
                << " name=" << paramName.at(i)  
                << " val="  << paramValue[i]    
                << " min="  << paramMin[i] 
                << " max="  << paramMax[i]      
                << " ref="  << paramRef[i]
                << " type=" << paramType.at(i)          
            << endl;

cout    <<endl << "respTable" << endl;
for(int i=0; i<respNbRows; i++)
    cout    << "line " << i << " : "    
                << " name=" << respName.at(i)       
            << endl;

cout    <<endl << "objTable" << endl;
for(int i=0; i<objNbRows; i++)
    cout    << "line " << i << " : "    
                << " name=" << objName.at(i)        
                << " type=" << objType.at(i)    
            << endl;


cout    <<endl << "conTable" << endl;
for(int i=0; i<conNbRows; i++)
    cout    << "line " << i << " : "    
                << " name=" << conName.at(i)    
                << " type=" << conType.at(i)
                << " limit="<< conLimit[i] 
                << " exp="  << conExponent[i]       
                << " refV=" << conRefVal[i]
                << " wght=" << conWeight[i]         
            << endl;


cout    <<endl << "intConTable" << endl;
for(int i=0; i<intConNbRows; i++)
    cout    << "line " << i << " : "    
                << " name=" << intConName.at(i) 
                << " type=" << intConType.at(i)
                << " lowL=" << intConLowLimit[i] 
                << " uprL=" << intConUpLimit[i]     
                << " exp="  << intConExponent[i]
                << " wght=" << intConWeight[i]          
            << endl;
            
cout << endl << "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

return;
}

///////////////////////////////////////// test functions
// Test function
void rosenbrockFunction (std::vector<double>& parameterVector, std::vector<double>& responseVector)
{
double r = 0;

for (unsigned int i=0; i<parameterVector.size (); i++)
    if ( (i+1)%2 == 1 )
        r = r + pow(1.0E+00 - parameterVector.at (i), 2.0);
    else
        r = r + 100.0E+00 * 
        pow(parameterVector.at (i) - pow(parameterVector.at (i-1), 2.0), 2.0);

responseVector.at (0) = r;
}

// Test function
void zdt1Function (std::vector<double>& parameterVector, std::vector<double>& responseVector)
{
double nDouble = parameterVector.size ();

double f1 = parameterVector.at (0);
double g = 0.0;
for (unsigned int i=1; i<parameterVector.size (); i++)
    g += parameterVector.at (i);
g = 9.0 * g / (nDouble - 1.0);
g += 1.0;
double h = 1.0 - sqrt (f1 / g);

responseVector.at (0) = f1;
responseVector.at (0) = g * h;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MainFrame_Jni_Functions_runTestGA  (JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj){

//testGA();

//xtremeDataGA = XtremeDataGA();
XtremeDataGA xtremeData = XtremeDataGA();

//--------------- [ Parameters ] ----------------------------------------------------
xtremeData.parameters.resize (2); //paramNbRows

for(int i=0; i<2; i++){ //paramNbRows

    xtremeData.parameters.at(i).name        = paramName.at(i);
    xtremeData.parameters.at(i).valueMin    = paramMin[i];
    xtremeData.parameters.at(i).valueMax    = paramMax[i];
    xtremeData.parameters.at(i).valueRef    = paramRef[i];

    if      (!strcmp(paramType.at(i), "Double"))    
        xtremeData.parameters.at(i).valueType = 3;
    else if (!strcmp(paramType.at(i), "Integer"))
        xtremeData.parameters.at(i).valueType = 2;
    else if (!strcmp(paramType.at(i), "Boolean"))
        xtremeData.parameters.at(i).valueType = 1;
    else
        xtremeData.parameters.at(i).valueType = 0;
}

//--------------- [ Responses ] -----------------------------------------------------
xtremeData.responses.resize (1);

xtremeData.responses.at(0).name   = "F1";

//--------------- [ External simulation ] -------------------------------------------
xtremeData.externalSimulation.externalSimulationType    = 1;
xtremeData.externalSimulation.functionPointer           = &rosenbrockFunction;

//--------------- [ Objective function ] --------------------------------------------
xtremeData.penalties.resize (1);
xtremeData.penalties.at(0).quantityName = "F1";
xtremeData.penalties.at(0).penaltyType  = "MINIMIZE";
xtremeData.penalties.at(0).weight       = 1.0;

//--------------- [ Optimizer ] -----------------------------------------------------
xtremeData.optimizationData.initialSolutionStrategy = 0;
xtremeData.optimizationData.randomSeedStrategy      = 0;

xtremeData.optimizationGAData.reproductionCount = 50;
xtremeData.optimizationGAData.individualCount   = 50;

xtremeData.optimizationGAData.evaluationStrategy.first  = 1;
xtremeData.optimizationGAData.evaluationStrategy.second = 1;
xtremeData.optimizationGAData.GAType                    = 1; // our advance GA

xtremeData.optimizationData.solutionHistoryStrategy = 1;

bool success = XtremeAPIGA (xtremeData);

cout << endl << "success=" << success << endl;


cout << "nb1=" << xtremeData.resultsData.parameter.size() << endl;
cout << "nb2=" << xtremeData.resultsData.parameter.at(0).size() << endl;
cout << "nb3=" << xtremeData.resultsData.parameter.at(0).at(0).size() << endl;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

cout << "begin!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" << endl;

cout << "before!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" << endl;
jclass jclazz = env->FindClass("MainFrame/Jni/TablesObjects");
cout << "after***************" << jclazz <<endl;


int iterationsSize = xtremeData.resultsData.parameter.size();
jdouble* jdbl = new jdouble(iterationsSize);
for(int i=0; i<iterationsSize; i++)
    jdbl[i] = xtremeData.resultsData.parameter.at(i).at(0).at(0);
jdoubleArray jdblArr = env->NewDoubleArray(iterationsSize);
env->SetDoubleArrayRegion(jdblArr, 0, iterationsSize, jdbl);


jclass jStringClass   = env->FindClass("java/lang/String"); 
jobjectArray jStringArray = env->NewObjectArray(6, jStringClass, 0);
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(jStringArray, i, env->NewStringUTF("a") );


jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(jclazz, "resultsParameterInsertCol", "([Ljava/lang/Object;[D)V");
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(jclazz, mid, jStringArray, jdblArr);

cout << "end!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" << endl;
}


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MainFrame_Jni_Functions_destroyAll  (JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj){

// parameters table columns and row number
paramName;
paramType;
paramValue = NULL;
paramMin = NULL;
paramMax = NULL;
paramRef = NULL;
paramNbRows;

// responses table columns and row number
respName;
respNbRows = NULL;

// objectives table columns and row number
objName;
objType;
objNbRows = NULL;

// constraints table columns and row number
conName;
conType;
conLimit = NULL;
conExponent = NULL;
conRefVal = NULL;
conWeight = NULL;
conNbRows = NULL;

// interval constraints table columns and row number
intConName;
intConType;
intConLowLimit = NULL;
intConUpLimit = NULL;
intConExponent = NULL;
intConWeight = NULL;
intConNbRows = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Can you show some more code to illustrate for problem?

Comment: Problem solved, my double array was bad initialized... I used "()" instead of "[]" ...

Answer (score 0):

All native libraries loads to your ClassLoader's static map, so you can't simply reload native library in one JVM. The way how to figure out with this stuff you can look at DLL's interface it should contain something like destroy, destroyN method, so library can finalize its resources itself.

Comment: I added some C++ code, I began a method that's gonna set variables to null, am I doing it the good way ? Any suggestion plz ? ^^

Comment: You should add some method on C++ side : 
int init();
destroy(int);
This methods will manage instances of your C++ object, I'm not C++ guru but I know that you shouldn't manage this from java side.